# Arrays being unable to return any value after being accessed by a particular function

Tags: c, arrays, variables, filter, io

I'm trying to filter my data to get rid of some noise, and I found that when I to run the filter the data from the original array with the pre-filtered data and the second array with the filtered data both become unprintable.

This is where I called the filter function(s):

```
int main(void)
{   
int n = 0;
double sum=0.0;
USART1_Config();
ADC1_Init();
IIR_Reset();
while(1)
{
     if(DMA_GetFlagStatus(DMA1_FLAG_TC1)==SET)      
     {
       sgolayfilt();
       IIR_filter();
       for(i=0;i<256;i++)
     {          
     Send_int_Data[i]=(int)(Send_float_Data[i]*1000);

         printf("%d\n",ADC_ConvertedValue[i]);
         //printf("%d\n",Send_int_Data[i]);     
         }
        DMA_ClearFlag(DMA1_FLAG_TC1);
} 
}
}
```

This is for sgolayfilt, the function that messes up the data(I even tried printing the pre-filter array right after I called the function, but even that didn't give me any values):

```
float sqr(float x) {
return x*x;
}

int linreg(int n, float x[], float y[], float* m, float* b, float* r){
float   sumx = 0.0;                  
float   sumx2 = 0.0;                    
float   sumxy = 0.0;                     
float   sumy = 0.0;                      
float   sumy2 = 0.0;                     
    float denom;

for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    { 
    sumx  += x[i];       
    sumx2 += sqr(x[i]);  
    sumxy += x[i] * y[i];
    sumy  += y[i];      
    sumy2 += sqr(y[i]);
} 

denom = (n * sumx2 - sqr(sumx));
if (denom == 0) {
    // singular matrix. can't solve the problem.
    *m = 0;
    *b = 0;
    //if (r) *r = 0;
        return 1;
}

*m = (n * sumxy  -  sumx * sumy) / denom;
*b = (sumy * sumx2  -  sumx * sumxy) / denom;

if (r!=NULL) {
    *r = (sumxy - sumx * sumy / n) /    
          sqrt((sumx2 - sqr(sumx)/n) *
          (sumy2 - sqr(sumy)/n));
}
return 0; 
}

void sgolayfilt(void){
    //for(i=0;i<256;i++) printf("%d\n",ADC_ConvertedValue[i]);
    if (!check)
    {
        for (i=0;i<4;i++)
        {
            ADC_ConvertedValueLocal = (float) 
            ADC_ConvertedValue[i]/4096*2.5;
            placeholder[i] = ADC_ConvertedValueLocal;
        }   
        check = 1;
    }
    for(i=0;i<256;i++)
    {
        if(i<4)
        {
            for(j=i;j<4;j++) y[j-i] = placeholder[j];
            for(j=4-i;j<8;j++) 
            {
                ADC_ConvertedValueLocal = (float) 
                ADC_ConvertedValue[j+i-4]/4096*2.5;
                y[j] = ADC_ConvertedValueLocal;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for(j=i-4;j<i+4;j++)
            {
                ADC_ConvertedValueLocal = (float) 
                ADC_ConvertedValue[j]/4096*2.5;
                y[j-i+4] = ADC_ConvertedValueLocal;
            }
        }
        pass = linreg(8, x, y, &m, &b, &r);
        if (pass==0) Send_float_Data[i] = (5 * m + b);
        else 
        {
            ADC_ConvertedValueLocal = (float) 
            ADC_ConvertedValue[i]/4096*2.5;
            Send_float_Data[i] = ADC_ConvertedValueLocal;   
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<4;i++) placeholder[i] = y[4+i];
}
```

This is for the original filter that works just fine save the actual filtering:

```
void IIR_filter(void)
{
  for(i=0;i<256;i++)
  {
    ADC_ConvertedValueLocal =(float) ADC_ConvertedValue[i]/4096*2.5;
    x0=ADC_ConvertedValueLocal;
    w0[0]=IIR_50Notch_A[0]*x0-IIR_50Notch_A[1]*w0[1]- 
    IIR_50Notch_A[2]*w0[2];
    y0=IIR_50Notch_B[0]*w0[0]+IIR_50Notch_B[1]*w0[1]+IIR_50Notch_B[2]*w0
    [2];

    x1=y0;

    w1[0]=IIR_High_A[0]*x1-IIR_High_A[1]*w1[1]-IIR_High_A[2]*w1[2];
    y1=IIR_High_B[0]*w1[0]+IIR_High_B[1]*w1[1]+IIR_High_B[2]*w1[2];
    Send_float_Data[i]=y1;

    w0[2]=w0[1];
    w0[1]=w0[0];
    w1[2]=w1[1];
    w1[1]=w1[0];
}   
}
```

And these are the variable declarations:

```
__IO unsigned char s[50];// 

extern __IO uint16_t ADC_ConvertedValue[256];
__IO float ADC_ConvertedValueLocal;  
__IO float Send_float_Data[256];
__IO int Send_int_Data[256];
volatile char Send_char_data[4];
__IO float placeholder[4];

float w0[3]={0};
float w1[3]={0};
float x0=0,x1=0;
float y0=0,y1=0;
float x[8] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
float y[8];
float m,b,r;
unsigned int pass;

unsigned int i=0,j;

_Bool check = 0;
```

I don't have much experience with C and so I'm looking for help on how should I modify my code so that "sgolayfilt()" interacts with the data like "IIR_filter" does and not mess up the arrays.

**EDIT** After going back and looking through it a bit more the pre-filter array "ADC_ConvertedValue" encounters the error the moment I call the faulty function. I placed the two function calls in the same place and the "printf" statements at the very start of the function definitions themselves and the original can print the values within the array regardless while the faulty function can't.

Comment: Too  hard to understand your question. It's too long and does not go to the main point.

Comment: @Nik If you mean the code is too long then I have to apologize, I'm just trying to put as much information as possible so that someone could analyze all the places where I could have made a mistake.
I'll try to make the answer itself more clear and to the point as well, thanks.

Comment: Please study and apply the concept of making a [mcve]. It might even give you the answer directly.

Comment: Avoid introducing anything which is named beginning with a "_".

Comment: What do you mean by "unprintable"? What output do you expect? What output do you get instead?

Comment: Have you enabled all warnings for the compiler? They might tell you something useful. I tried to compile, but there are declarations missing.

Comment: @Yuunosch I would try to shorten it but my problem is that I don't know what exactly is causing the problem, is it a mismatch of variable types, a call to a function that isn't allowed, variable types going out of bounds...

If your talking about the _Bool I can probably change that, __IO is something I don't think I can change though.

I'm testing the program out using Serial Port Utility, and by "unprintable" I mean nothing is displayed as the output when I use the faulty function whereas it gives me a proper set of numbers when I use the other one.

Comment: It is probably not the cause of the problem, but declaring the variable `i` globally does not look like good practice. Declare it in each function where it is needed, or, with C99, in the `for` loop itself.

Comment: General debugging hints: add more printf to see what is going on; cut out things and make the program smaller and smaller while still exhibiting the error.

Comment: @Arndt I think those might be the constant arrays "IIR_50Notch_A" and so on used in IIR_filter, that was one of the things that I thought didn't need to be included to solve the problem.

Comment: @ArndtJonasson Hi, I generally wouldn't declare it globally either, but that was what the writer of the original filter did and when I tried to change it initially to within the for loop it gave me error 29: expected expression. I decided to let it be for the time being and focus on this problem, which is getting weirder the more I try to debug it.